# Tried to connect two columns together but getting extra records MySql

Tags: mysql

I have table called **tcs** and **mcs**, and each table contains column called '**adj_close**', so i have been trying to connect these together by using query, but i'm getting extra records as shown in below.

```
select a.adj_close, b.adj_close from (select adj_close from tcs order by date desc limit 2) as a, (select adj_close from mcs order by date desc limit 2) as b;
```

**Output:**

```
+------------------+---------------+
| adj close        | adj close     |
+------------------+---------------+
| 2222.35009765625 |       37      |
| 2204.35009765625 |       37      |
| 2222.35009765625 |       39      |
| 2204.35009765625 |       39      |
+------------------+---------------+
```

**and I'm expecting output as shown below**,

```
    +------------------+------------------+
    | adj close        | adj close        |
    +------------------+------------------+
    | 2222.35009765625 |      37          |
    | 2204.35009765625 |      39          |
    +------------------+------------------+
```

I think this is something to do with joins, i'm new to database. please help!

Comment: Please read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Eric sorry, i'm new here.

Comment: Or this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I'll be nice and second-guess that it is probably something like this:

```sql
SELECT tcs.adj_close, msc.adj_close
  FROM tcs, mcs
WHERE tcs.date = mcs.date
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 2
```

**Update:** It is probably a good idea to show the date in the output as well, but sticking close to your example gives this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're doing a Cross-Join (selecting data from multiple tables without any relationship or restriction).

Here you have 2 ways to solve this:

1. Using Join

```
SELECT
    A.ADJ_CLOSE,
    B.ADJ_CLOSE
FROM
    TCS AS A JOIN MCS AS B
    ON A.ADJ_CLOSE = B.ADJ_CLOSE
ORDER BY
    A.DATE DESC
LIMIT
    2;
```

2. Using WHERE

```
SELECT
    A.ADJ_CLOSE,
    B.ADJ_CLOSE
FROM
    (SELECT ADJ_CLOSE FROM TCS ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 2) AS A,
    (SELECT ADJ_CLOSE FROM MCS ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 2) AS B
WHERE
    A.ADJ_CLOSE = B.ADJ_CLOSE;
```